# Broken 3ds XL Transfer to New 3ds XL?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

So recently I spilled some water on my New 3ds XL and I received a few error screens before the next day when it completely stopped working. It would turn on and I could still hear the music from the home screen, but both screens were black. (“The black screen of death”). Yesterday, I got a new New 3ds XL and of course I am unable to do the transfer of data since my broken N3dsXL isn’t working. But I was wondering if there was any way at all I could transfer the data? Or not and I’m just gonna have to start fresh? (I just really really care about my Activity Log honestly).

Comment: For future reference: If you ever spill water on an electronic device, turn it off immediately. Just putting it to standby isn't enough. If you can, remove the battery as soon as you're able to. Finally, wait for the device to dry up completely before turning it on again. Contacts may rust when they get in contact with water, but short circuits are way worse.

Comment: If the only malfunctions are the screens, it's possible you'll still be able to input the commands blindly, it's a stretch since the home screen layout is dynamic on the 3DS so your settings app icon (the one you'll need to start the transfer process) may be located differently than on a stock 3DS, but it's worth a shot.